# np.convolve and signal.convolve hard fault after freezing using pyinstaller

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, pyinstaller

So I have been debugging this bug for the last 10 hours. The problem is that I wrote a program that get's data from a usb scope and processes it, but after I frooze it using pyinstaller it would crash without any error. I made test program and by adding print statements throughout my code I traced down the bug to this one line:

```
y = signal.convolve(prev_values,filter_b,mode ='valid')
```

I tried replacing this line with:

```
y = np.convolve(prev_values,filter_b,mode ='valid')
```

but that also crashes. I tried replacing the line with

```
y = np.ones(len(prev_values)-len(filter_b)+1)
```

and everything is fine. The command I use to freeze my app is:

```
pyinstaller --log-level=DEBUG --add-binary "./dlls/*;./" --add-binary "./interface.ui;./" --add-binary "./settings.yaml;./" "app.py"
```

The problem now is that I have now idea where this goes wrong. Is it python having some memory issues or something? Or could both numpy and scipy have a bug that causes this? Or is it something with pyinstaller? Any tips are welcome. Also if you know a good alternative to do a convolution for numpy and signal.

Answer (score -1):

this np.convolve function was also essencial for my app and also was giving me some problems while using pyinstaller. What happened is that my numpy library was up to date while my pyinstaller wasn't, so i think all the hooks, that called the aproppriate dlls and etc to make everything work, were wrong. I've tried to manually fix it adding all the missing stuff manually, but in the end updating pyinstaller made everything work without any further issue.

No python expert here, but I hope updating everything helps you.

Comment: This is not a complete answer, more of a comment. I understand you cannot post comments with your current reputation level but refrain of giving incomplete answers